# Trying to convert SAS code to R (mixed effects model)

Tags: sas, mixed-models

I have the following code in SAS:

```
PROC MIXED DATA = mydata;
  CLASS time;
  MODEL y = trt time / SOLUTION;
  REPEATED time / SUBJECT = patient_id TYPE = UN;
RUN;
```

I would like to run this in R, but the output does not match. I tried this

```
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(y ~ trt + time + (1 | patient_id), data = mydata)
```

I was expecting a p-value for trt of less than 0.05 but in R it is more than 0.1. Also, none of the other output matches. I assume it is something related to TYPE = UN, but I don't know how to do that with lme4. Maybe lme4 can't do that, in which case how do I achieve similar results ?

Comment: Can you add a link to the data or make a reproducible example ? Probably the issue is related to the UN covariance structure which is not supported by lme4 so you will need to use a different R package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is not a single random-intercepts one, but considers the outcome as multivariate normal. The **R** (and thereby **V**) part of your variance-covariance has as many distinct rows and columns as you have timepoints, a single random intercept would apply to all timepoints equally.

This is identical in interpretation (but not computation or variance parametrization!) to having a random intercept per timepoint. Alternatives that get you the same result to within convergence precision should be:

1. changing the SAS `repeated` statement into `random`, making the model actually random-effects using **G**-side parametrization with a single residual variance profiled out. This is just to show how different parametrizations match in their interpretation, it's a more complicated/slower computation to get to the same result but will do "exactly" what the R alternatives do.
2. Using `(time | patient_id)` as the random effect in R (assuming `time` is a factor). **Edit**: after trying this out `lme4` might only want to do this if you add `control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = 'ignore')` and will still produce convergence warnings while returning the same estimates as SAS, so #3 (or `nlme`) might be the better option for MMRMs in R.
3. Using R's [`mmrm`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mmrm) package which was purpose-built to reproduce these kind of models, the random effect becomes `us(time | patient_id)` (again assuming both are factors). This will also allow you to match several degrees of freedom approximations from SAS (if you're interpreting *P*-values you are using an appropriate degrees of freedom approximation, right?).

What the SAS `random` and `repeated` statements do exactly is explained in detail in the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_mixed_details01.htm#statug_mixed009830), a key point to remember when translating to R is that the implementations there usually only do actual random (**G**-side) effects. I've never done so myself but recall reading that `nlme` may be more flexible in this regard than `lme4`, though for models like this it doesn't matter since you can get them to match either way.

[Here](https://thestatsgeek.com/2020/12/30/mixed-model-repeated-measures-mmrm-in-stata-sas-and-r/)'s a blog (not mine) that looks at implementing MMRMs across different software packages as well.

Comment: This is a great answer which deserves several upvotes, shame that I'm limited to 1 !

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @PBulls excellent answer, in your SAS model you are specifying an *unstructured* variance-covariance matrix by using the syntax `TYPE = UN`. `lme4` does not support this, so you would need to use a different package. @PBulls mentions the new `mmrm` package, and I would just like to add that `glmmTMB` (among others) should be able to fit this model:

```
library(glmmTMB)
glmmTMB(y ~ trt + time + us(0 + time | patient_id), family = gaussian(), data = mydata)
```

Comment: I actually thought that `lme4` could *only* do unstructured - see for example [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/varmats.html), but I've seen similar claims to yours as well (e.g. the very blog post I linked in my answer). However, I've always relied on SAS to run my mixed models because despite the language's shortcomings `PROC MIXED` and `PROC NLMIXED` are just without match (though R is catching up rapidly).

Comment: @PBulls hmm, now you've got me thinking :D. I don't have time to check Ben's hacking page, but will try to check over the weekend, but one thought that crossed my mind about it (I have had a look briefly before) is that it was about the VCV of the random effects themselves, not the residual error structure within subjects ?

Comment: @PBulls I'm a fairly recent convert to SAS having recently done a short contract where the majority of the time was comparing various R packages to SAS (a little biit like Julia Dedic did in her [`mmrm` paper.](https://phuse.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Archive/2023/Connect/US/Florida/PAP_OS05.pdf)

Comment: @PBulls I just had a look at the [hacking covariance structures page](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/varmats.html]) and as I suspected it seems to be about the random effect covariance (ie the covariance between random intercepts and slopes) that is output in the `Random effects:` section of the `summary` output. Had it also been computing a residual error covariance structure there would be a **lot** of additional estimates , t(t+1)/2, where t is the number of time points.

Comment: Yes, but those are effectively the same - the whole point between both parametrizations matching. Going back to the SAS notation **V** = **ZGZ'+R**, where **G** is the random effects covariance (**Z** its design matrix) and **R** the residual (co)variance. `repeated` makes **R** a t by t matrix (and without random statement there is no **Z** or **G**), whereas `random` makes **G** a t by t matrix (and without repeated **R** is a scalar, profiled out of the diagonal of **G** by SAS which is where `lme4` complains about it being confounded). Most R packages only support one of the two.

Comment: (contd.) Because of **G** and **R** parametrizations being exchangeable *for the MMRM* (same **V** in the end) it doesn't matter whether you use `repeated` or `random` in SAS (again, not in how results are actually computed; `repeated` is much more stable/straigthforward), nor which package in R. This wouldn't be true if you need a combination of these statements, for example to model heteroscedasticity across treatment groups via **R** while handling clustering/repeated measures via **G** - I think `nlme` might be able to do something like that but pretty sure both `lme4` and `mmrm` can't.